# reading variable from file becomes text

Tags: bash, variables

I must read include-lines from a script. The include-lines are build by variables. When I ls the file based on these variables, its working fine. When I do the same after I have collected the line into my array, the variables behave like somehow invisible changed from $VAR to \$VAR

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
DIR=scratchpad
SCRIPT=$(basename $0)
echo $DIR/$SCRIPT
ls -1 $DIR/$SCRIPT

f_doNothing () {
. $DIR/$SCRIPT
}

while read LINE ; do
    if [[ "$LINE" = ". "* ]] ; then
        LINE=${LINE/. /}
        LINE=${LINE/\#*/}
        LINE=${LINE//\"/}
        LIBS+=($LINE)
        echo ${LIBS[@]}
        ls -l ${LIBS[@]}
    fi
done < <(cat $DIR/$SCRIPT)
```

The two last lines of output show the damaged variable and the non-working ls.

```
$ ./read_include.sh
scratchpad/read_include.sh
scratchpad/read_include.sh
$DIR/$SCRIPT
ls: cannot access $DIR/$SCRIPT: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The value of the variable is literally `$DIR/$SCRIPT`. When executing `ls -l ${LIBS[@]}` it is expanded but only once, not recursively. If you want to expand the value of the variable see `eval`. As `eval` is not recommended you could also design something more complex based on indirection or namerefs. But you'll have to isolate and process each variables (`DIR`, `SCRIPT`) independently. Anyway, what is the point in trying to recursively expand something while you already know the result?

Comment: Hi Renaud,
yes absolutely true, I know already what should be in the variables. This is just a massive simplified version of what I need to achieve. I just wanted to keep the example-script easy to read and in one single file.

Thanks for the eval-hint, I tried that already, but failed. Would you add an eval-example please?

Comment: Just `eval "ls -l ${LIBS[@]}"` instead of `ls -l ${LIBS[@]}`. But remember please that all this is not recommended. There are many potential issues.

Comment: THANKS, I have added LINE=$(eval "echo $LINE") before adding LINE to the array and its working fine now. I will think about a more secure implementation without eval.